# Value Errors on tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I write a simple code with the tensorflow toolkit as follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
if __name__=="__main__":
   inp = np.random.randint(1,3,(1,20,300,1))
   inputs = tf.convert_to_tensor(inp,dtype=tf.float32)
   with tf.variable_scope('convpool1') as scope:
       kernel = tf.get_variable('weights',[1,300,1,1],initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=5e-2,dtype=tf.float32))
       conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs,kernel,[1,1,1,1],padding='VALID')

   init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
   with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        with tf.variable_scope('convpool1'):
            k_ = sess.run(kernel)
            c1_ =sess.run(conv1)
```

It works when I run this code first time,but when I run the same again,it raises an　Error:

```
Variable convpool1/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?
```

And I restart the IDE(spyder), run this code,it works again.What could be the origin of this error and how i can resolve it? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Every time you run this snippet, it's appending to the default graph. You can `tf.reset_default_graph()` to start anew

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

at the beginning should resolve your problem.  I am not 100% sure but suspect spyder still have the Graph object (and thus the var scope is already created).

Comment: Glad to help, remember to accept the answer if you have resolved the problem.  =)